# Constructors: get type list from argument list

Tags: java, constructor, arguments

I'm currently working on a program where I will be dynamically loading classes at runtime and am building a library of functions to support it.  One of these functions is a method to easily search a given jar file for a given class name and create a new instance from the given set of initialization arguments.

The issue is arguments. I know how to find a constructor for a class for a set of class types, however, trying to find a constructor that accepts a list of arguments is harder.  My first thought was to iterate through the arguments and call `getClass()` on each, but what about null arguments which may well be a valid thing for some constructors?

Is there any sensible way to find the correct constructor for a given set of arguments?

NOTE: standard Java only, this is a joint project so Java derived languages and 3rd party libraries are not available.

Answer (score 2):

Did you go through [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorLocation.html) tutorial?? It has the implementation for exactly what you want..

Comment: In addition you could add note about ClassLoader

Comment: I can handle classloading, and have used that in the past.  Realistically most of the functions I intend to do with dynamic loading will just use the empty constructor and then an initialisation function (which is more application specific), but as it's a library I'm writing at the moment I'm trying ot keep it flexible

Answer (score 1):

After you pass the Reflection API Tutorial, you can use single method for your problem

```
private final boolean checkConstructor(Class<?> type, Class<?>... parameterTypes)  {

        try {
             forName.getConstructor(parameterTypes);
             return true;
        }catch(NoSuchMethodException e) {

        }

        return false;
    }
```

What you have to remember that order of the `paraemterTypes` is important.

You should not allo to sytiation where you call for a constructor not knowing the parametersTypes. Same rule apply to code style that you should not use null in the constructors.

Comment: You mean just get the classes, reject it if there are nulls (not resolvable) and try and catch?  I had considered that as my backup solution, but was interested to know if there were more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 0):

getClass() is a right approach. You have to iterate over all accessible constructors and choose most specific one acting according to the spirit of [Choosing the Constructor and its Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.3), including throwing exeptions if 0 or >1 constructors found, and boxing/unboxing as in [Determine Method Signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2). You cannot implement that algorithms literally because of nulls, but should keep as close as possible.